# nodejs/passport - Error: OAuthStrategy requires session support

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, passport.js

I am trying to set up a twitter connect on my web app using the passport module

I have implemented it as follow:

App.js file:

```
 /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express     = require('express');
var user        = require('./server/routes/user');
var http        = require('http');
var path        = require('path');
var app         = express();
var passport    = require('passport');
var flash       = require('connect-flash');

require('./server/config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.configure(function() {

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // set up our express application
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
    app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

    // required for passport
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'SECRET' })); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

});


// // routes ======================================================================
require('./server/routes/index')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport
```

I am using express.session but i get the following error message when trying to authenticate:

```
Error: OAuthStrategy requires session support. Did you forget app.use(express.session(...))?
```

Does anyone has an idea why I get this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The order of loaded Express middlewares is not right. Try this:

```
// ...

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  // The following two middlwares are NOT necessary because bodyParser includes them.
  // app.use(express.json());
  // app.use(express.urlencoded());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());

  app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
  app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
  // required for passport
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'SECRET' })); // session secret
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
  app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

// ...
```

Comment: As of Express 4.*, official middleware is stored in separate repos. E.g., `var session = require('express-session'); app.use(session({ secret: 'SECRET' }));` https://github.com/senchalabs/connect

Answer (score 10):

For 4.0 this changes a bit.

First, you'll need to install `express-session` and then, before you define your routes:

```
// Authentication configuration
app.use(session({
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'bla bla bla' 
}));
```

You can latter you do the OAuth thing:

```
// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
   ...
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `express-session` to your main js file.

```
const session = require('express-session');
// After you declare "app"
app.use(session({ secret: 'melody hensley is my spirit animal' }));
```

Just like these guys do it for the [LinkedIn commit](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/pull/51/commits/a068c1edf39b1243893d97733c2bd7ea3ce29d35).

Obviously don't forget to install `express-session`, so `npm install express-session` or add `"express-session": "^1.15.3"` to your package.json

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the latest express (3.0)
replace the cookie parser line with the following:

app.use(express.cookieParser("thissecretrocks"));

Worked for me for same error !!